# Google sheets: cumulative addition of cells in a row, based upon a boolean condition in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I'm trying to establish add up a series of cell values in a single row of a  google sheet. The sheet records invoices against an associated purchase order. Usually, there are multiple invoices in a schedule for each PO. I want to be able to create a method for looping through a row, and adding up the invoice amount IF the drop down value of yes has been selected.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hrJlcfT7y_gKWb0E1qUrn7wiJq1bdNl5kCZhum-TV3w/edit?usp=sharing

Currently the formula in A3 is looping though: and totaling every invoice value (i.e. in D3, H3, L3, P3 etc):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(B3:Y3),4)=0),B3:Y3)
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this with the conditional value in another cell (E3, I3, M3, Q3.... etc). Any ideas if this is possible, and if so, any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

Offset the next range and check if `yes`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(B3:Y3),4)=0),B3:Y3,--(C3:Z3 = "yes"))
```